# Join Nested Structure Table using Dataflow Java code

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My objective is to join two tables, where the second table is normal and the first one is nested structure table. The join key is available inside the nested structure in first table. In this case, how to Join these two tables using dataflow java code. WithKeys (org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.WithKeys) accepting direct column name and it does not allow like `firstTable.columnname`. Could some one to help to solve this case.
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to have this nested structure in the output table? Can we just flatten the output to be: Cusname, Custno, headerid, cr.date, lineid, item desc? It will make it much easier tbh ..

Comment: I have answered same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539922/how-to-unnest-the-nested-pcollection-in-dataflow/56537739#56537739) which is in python with apache Beam, might be helpful to you. in ParDo addkeysnested function, i am getting key values from nested field. by using this code you don't need to unnest the fields. so we don't require to change the schema structure of table.

Answer (score 1):

If both tables are equally large consider using the CoGroupByKey transform described [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/). You will have to transform your data into two PCollections keyed by the proper key before this operation.

If one table is significantly smaller than the other, feeding the smaller PCollection as a side input to a ParDo over the larger PCollection as described [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) might be a better option.

Comment: If our Collection has Unnest type, CoGroupByKey will works for Joining two collections, since common key can be readable from unnest collections by WithKey().However If the common key is inside of the nested collection then CoGbkResult having empty value, since the common key presents inside of the nested structure, so it doesn't match and throw the collections is empty. In this case, do you think that we need to do the unnest the nested collection every time before we join the collection or do we have any other idea for joining nested collection?.I have attached screen shot for reference.

Comment: Yes, I believe you'll have to unnest key from your elements and define a KV of PCollections with the proper key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please give example in java.

Comment: I just follow the below stackoverflow link for Joining the Collection. WithKeys method can't accepting nested column based grouping the collection like "firstTable.columnname". Could you assist, how to give nested columns join in the WithKeys function.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175971/how-to-join-bq-tables-on-two-or-more-keys-with-cloud-dataflow/50223215#50223215

Comment: Would you like to try BeamSQL? BeamSQL allows JOIN on inner field of nested type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Okay, I will explore BeamSQL and get back to you with my feedback later some time. In between, I was trying to Unnest the nested PCollection using org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.Unnest class, but still getting nested structure in the ParDo fn. Here is the high level step, 1. Read the Table using BigQueryIO 2.Convert from com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow to org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row
3. Apply Unnest class 4.Convert the Row to TableRow. It would be good if you share any sample code with Unnest class.

Comment: @Rui Wang, Could you please share any sample code to Join with inner field of nested type using BeamSQL?

Comment: @lourdurajan Here is an example: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/PubsubToBigqueryIT.java#L91. As you can see, BeamSQL support a table with Row type. Row type can has another Row as its field. So you will be able to access row.row.row....field, which can be put in the join condition.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Tried to use BeamSql for unnesting the nested collection. Lets assume the PCollection which have the Employees and its details are in nested collection. So if we use the BeamSQL like "SELECT `PCOLLECTION`.`details` FROM PCOLLECTION" then getting details alone in separate PCollection<Row>. But when we want to specific column from the detail  nested collection, then getting error like unable to find the column name. Tried to use the BeamSQL like "SELECT X.address FROM PCOLLECTION, Unnest(details) as X" then getting nullpointer exception. Please help on this.